# Can't get ffi-rzmq zeromq gem working on Windows

Tags: ruby, zeromq, ffi

I've having trouble getting the ffi-rzmq gem to work on windows.

I've installed the windows installer for ZeroMQ 2.2 from here:
http://www.zeromq.org/distro:microsoft-windows

And I've added C:\Program Files\ZeroMQ 2.2.0\bin to my PATH variable.

I then installed the ffi and ffi-rzmq gems with

```
gem install ffi
gem install ffi-rzmq
```

But when I start an irb and run:

```
require 'ffi-rzmq'
```

I get this message:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'ffi-rzmq'
Unable to load this gem. The libzmq library (or DLL) could not be found.
If this is a Windows platform, make sure libzmq.dll is on the PATH.
For non-Windows platforms, make sure libzmq is located in this search path:
["C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-rzmq-0.9.3/lib/ffi-rz
mq/../../ext/libzmq.dll", "/usr/local/lib/libzmq.dll", "/opt/local/lib/libzmq.dl
l", "/usr/local/homebrew/lib/libzmq.dll", "/usr/lib64/libzmq.dll"]
```

The weird thing is that the Zero MQ installer doesn't seem to package a libzmq.dll, only **libzmq-v100-mt.dll**

I'm sure I'm doing something very obvious that's wrong, but I can't see what it is... can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem - the error message given by ffi-rzmq has actually improved somewhat in the latest version.

Nathan was right that I had to rename the libzmq-v100-mt.dll to libzmq.dll, but that alone wasn't enough - I was using the 64bit compiled version of ZMQ, but for some reason ffi-rzmq is linked against the 32bit version.

So everything worked once I uninstalled the 64bit version, installed the 32bit version instead, reanamed the dll to libzmq.dll and adjusted my path to point to the 'c:\program files (x86)' version of zmq.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename libzmq-v100-mt.dll to libzmq.dll - I have no idea why they decided to have the windows build output a different library name.

I had the same problem, and as soon as I renamed the file zeromq started working fine.

(Okay, technically I had to fix my code first, but THEN zeromq worked fine).

Comment: I am also having this error - where is `libzmq-v100-mt.dll` located?